# How do you detect a touch of node in a shop scene and pass the value of that node to the GameScene in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I am new to swift and sprite kit and I am developing my first game.  I am trying to add a shop to my game, however, I can not get it to work the way that I want to.  I have a shop of skins that the user can choose from and what I want is for the user to touch on a skin.  If it is locked, then the user may purchase it with in game currency and it automatically shows as their current skin during gameplay.  If it isn't locked, then the user may press on it to make it their current skin during gameplay.  This is my current code:

```
import SpriteKit
```

class SkinsScene: SKScene {

```
var shopTextContainer = SKShapeNode()
var backtoMenuButton = SKSpriteNode()
var skinsText = SKLabelNode()
var coinBox = SKSpriteNode()
var coins = SKLabelNode()

/// Moveable node in the scrollView
var startY: CGFloat = 0.0
var lastY: CGFloat = 0.0
var moveableArea = SKNode()

//SKINS
let skinsArray = [
    ["skin0": "Character", "price": "Default", "locked":false],
    ["skin1": "blueCharacter", "price": "50", "locked": true],
    ["skin2": "basketballSkin", "price": "150", "locked": true]
]


static var currentSkin = "skin0"

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31/255, green: 30/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1.0)
    addTitle()

    /// add moveable node
    moveableArea.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.addChild(moveableArea)
    addSkins()
    let bottom = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Avenir-Black")
    bottom.text = "Bottom"
    bottom.fontSize = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)/20
    bottom.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:0-CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)*0.5)
    moveableArea.addChild(bottom)
}

func addTitle() {
    shopTextContainer = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 130))
    shopTextContainer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - 65)
    shopTextContainer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 133/255, green: 0, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1.0)
    shopTextContainer.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    shopTextContainer.zPosition = 20
    self.addChild(shopTextContainer)

    backtoMenuButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backButton")
    backtoMenuButton.position = CGPoint(x: -shopTextContainer.frame.width/2 + 55, y: 0)
    backtoMenuButton.zPosition = 25
    shopTextContainer.addChild(backtoMenuButton)

    skinsText.fontName = "DayPosterBlack"
    skinsText.fontSize = 50.0
    skinsText.text = "Skins"
    skinsText.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -23)
    skinsText.zPosition = 25
    shopTextContainer.addChild(skinsText)

    coinBox = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coinBox")
    coinBox.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
    coinBox.zPosition = 25
    shopTextContainer.addChild(coinBox)
    coins.fontName = "DayPosterBlack"
    coins.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    coins.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -6)
    coins.zPosition = 1
    coins.text = "0"
    coins.fontSize = 16.0
    coins.zPosition = 25
    coinBox.addChild(coins)
}

func addSkins() {

    for i in 0...skinsArray.count-1 {
        let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 283, height: 73), cornerRadius: 40.05)
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - 105*CGFloat(i) - 215)
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 133/255, green: 0, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1.0)
        shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 1/255, blue: 1/255, alpha: 0.78)
        shape.name = String(format: "skin%d", i)
        moveableArea.addChild(shape)

        let price = SKLabelNode()
        price.text = skinsArray[i]["price"] as? String
        price.fontSize = 15.0
        price.fontName = "DayPosterBlack"
        price.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        price.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -30)
        shape.addChild(price)

        let skin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: skinsArray[i][shape.name!] as! String)
        skin.zPosition = 1
        skin.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 4)
        shape.addChild(skin)

        if skinsArray[i]["locked"] == true {
            let locked = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lock")
            locked.position = CGPoint(x: -shape.frame.size.width/2 + 50, y: 0)
            shape.addChild(locked)
            skin.alpha = 0.45
        }
        else if skinsArray[i]["locked"] == false {
            let locked = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "unlock")
            locked.position = CGPoint(x: -shape.frame.size.width/2 + 50, y: 0)
            shape.addChild(locked)
            shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.4)
            skin.alpha = 1.0
        }

        if shape.name == SkinsScene.currentSkin {
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 65/255, green: 117/255, blue: 5/255, alpha: 1.0)
            shape.lineWidth = 3.0
        }
    }

}

/// Touches began,
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    // store the starting position of the touch

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let goBack = touch.locationInNode(shopTextContainer)
        startY = location.y
        lastY = location.y
        if backtoMenuButton.containsPoint(goBack){
            backtoMenuButton.alpha = 0.7
        }
        else {
            backtoMenuButton.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let goBack = touch.locationInNode(shopTextContainer)

        if backtoMenuButton.containsPoint(goBack){
            if GameScene.soundOn == true {
                self.scene?.runAction(buttonTouched)
            }
            let scene = ShopScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene,transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.8))
        }

        else {
            backtoMenuButton.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let currentY = location.y

        // Set Top and Bottom scroll distances, measured in screenlengths
        let topLimit:CGFloat = 0.0
        let bottomLimit:CGFloat = 0.6

        // Set scrolling speed - Higher number is faster speed
        let scrollSpeed:CGFloat = 1.0

        // calculate distance moved since last touch registered and add it to current position
        let newY = moveableArea.position.y + ((currentY - lastY)*scrollSpeed)

        // perform checks to see if new position will be over the limits, otherwise set as new position
        if newY < self.size.height*(-topLimit) {
            moveableArea.position = CGPointMake(moveableArea.position.x, self.size.height*(-topLimit))
        }
        else if newY > self.size.height*bottomLimit {
            moveableArea.position = CGPointMake(moveableArea.position.x, self.size.height*bottomLimit)
        }
        else {
            moveableArea.position = CGPointMake(moveableArea.position.x, newY)
        }

        // Set new last location for next time
        lastY = currentY
    }
}
```

You can see that I am making a rectangle with the skin from the array of dictionaries declared before the didMoveToView function. I had some code that attempted to detect the touch of the rectangle, but it isn't working, so I deleted it. I also tried to make a static variable called currentSkin to hold the skin and then pass it to my game scene, but that didn't work for me either.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understand well your question.
But if you want pass your `currentSkin` to **GameScene**, you can use a observe, a delegate or static var.

If you set static var current skin, you must write that variable.

in touch:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    // store the starting position of the touch

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if let name = touchedNode.name {
            if string.rangeOfString("skin") != nil {
                 SkinsScene.currentSkin = name
                 println(name)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Now you can call in GameScene:

```
let mySkin = SkinsScene.currentSkin
```

if your GameScene alredy exist, you must use delegate or observe.

Let me know you I understood well your question

Comment: I apologize if my question was a bit hard to understand, but you basically understand it.  For more clarification, I was asking how can I detect the touch of the many SKShapenodes I am creating to hold my skins in my function addSkin (since they aren't referenced before the didMoveToView), and then when the user taps on that SKShapenode, if the skin they pressed is unlocked, tell my GameScene which runs my game, to change the SKTexture of the character to that skin.  Then save that change of skin even when the game is closed.